# sharing singleton java class by Service and Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, singleton

Is there a potential issue using a Singleton Java class by both a Service and Activity in an Android application?

Example: Singleton is Singleton
Activity is A
Service S

Service S has a handle to Singleton. S requests Singleton to launch Activity. Activity calls operational methods defined in Singleton.

I have several Singletons in my application which encapsulate various operations for a functional area. So Activities will interact with various Singletons to perform various operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an issue with this approach. I use singletons quite often and never had any problems. You just need to keep in mind that android might remove the singleton instance when it needs the memory, so you need to check for null every time you get the singleton instance.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Glad to know this approach has worked for you without issues.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it won't introduce the issue. The only case You could expect it - using service running in separate process (service has [`android:process` attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestService_process) defined which starts with '.'). In that case You'll simply has two instances of the singleton - one for each process.